# Are Ph.D. programs easier to get into with an already obtained Master's?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states

To give specifics about my questions, I am on track to completing my Master's degree in Europe (Switzerland) and I have been looking at applying to the U.S. in case I cannot get a Ph.D. at my current school.

I have heard through the vines that since I will already have a Master's degree with a fair amount of work done related to research, it will make my application much more persuasive.

In this thread, I would like to confirm if that is true (or closer to the truth given the data)?

Answer (score 1):

The Masters degree is likely to help you in several respects: (1) through the experience you have gained from the research component; (2) through the coursework done in the program; and (3) through the extra year or two of general experience in your field.  Any previous experience, coursework, or research work, is going to be relevant in assessing your capacity to succeed in a PhD program, so unsurprisingly, a Masters degree in the same field or a related field is a positive.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say easier, but definitely different. There are a lot of tradeoffs. With only a bachelors, the path is quite long and starts, most places/fields, with advanced coursework. This is due to the fact that the US bachelors is a general degree, not especially specialized as it is in some other places, say Europe.

One normally (most places/fields) has to pass a set of comprehensive exams before the research is likely to get serious. Many potential advisors will wait until the student passes comps before committing to them. And the coursework itself implies that the faculty gets a good look at students before making serious commitments.

For someone with a masters, much more is expected. You may not be able to avoid comps and it might be expected that you have any necessary coursework, or most of it, already in hand, shortening the time to completion. But that also complicates the selection process since the faculty hasn't seen you in action very much and has to depend on what they find in the CV and letters of recommendation. And, a shorter time to completion isn't always in the best interest of the university, since, for those funded with a TA, there is less time for them to gain the skills needed for that and become an asset.

It might be "easier", however, in some fields, such as a lab science, in which a candidate already has certain skills that are needed for the lab but hard to obtain otherwise. If you can hit the ground running it might ease the path.

However, don't drop out of a masters because you think the other path leads to easier admittance. Just be aware that, in the US, most US trained students enter doctoral studies with a bachelors. In any case, it is what it is. The tradeoffs are what they are.

You are admitted on the same basic criteria no matter the degree held: measurable success in the past and the expectation of success in the future as indicated in admissions materials and especially letters of recommendation.

And, the way to know for sure about your own chances is to apply to a few programs.